# Chrome does not display pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

i have a problem,my code doesn't work on Chrome but is work fine in Firefox.Chrome does not show pseudo element probably like Firefox does.Here is a piece of my code.Please help and just ignore my bad English.Thank you.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vdloc/pen/VxgdMJ)

```
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because chrome applies the `overflow:hidden` to the `<hr>` element by default in user agent stylesheet. So you will need to apply `overflow:visible` to the `<hr>` element.

[image]

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  counter-reset: line 7;
}

hr {
  overflow: visible;
}

.graph__coordinate-line {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 5rem);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.graph__coordinate-line:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  counter-increment: line -1;
}

.graph__coordinate-line:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: " " counter(line) " K ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: -3.2rem;
}

.graph__coordinate-line:last-of-type::after {
  content: "0";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: -3.2rem;
}

.graph__coordinate-line::before {
  content: "\2013";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: -5rem;
}
```

```html
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
<hr class="graph__coordinate-line">
```